# Синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: php

Как записать что-бы работало?

```
    <p class="p_teacher_reg">ФИО:</p><?php echo "<p class='p'> "."  "$_SESSION['name']" "." "$_SESSION['surnamet']" "." "$_SESSION['last_name']"</p>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если включена короткая запись то лучше написать так

```
 <p class="p_teacher_reg">ФИО:</p>
 <p class="p">
    <?=$_SESSION['name']?> <?=$_SESSION['surnamet']?> <?=$_SESSION['last_name']?>
 </p>
```

Если же нет...

```
 <p class="p_teacher_reg">ФИО:</p>
 <p class="p">
     <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] .' '. $_SESSION['surnamet'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['last_name'];?>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="p_teacher_reg">ФИО:</p><?php echo "<p class='p'> ".$_SESSION['name']." ".$_SESSION['surnamet']." ".$_SESSION['last_name']."</p>"; ?>
```

ну можно и так.

Comment: можно, но не нужно...

Comment: если взять его первоначальный вариант то можно итак :) оптимизация дело нажитое

Comment: Причем тут оптимизация...

Банально попробуйте прочитать свой код( представьте что его много ) и мой... Никакой разницы не ощущаете кроме как оптимизация?